# Parsing JSON information from GIPHY API with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, parsing

I am currently trying to create an iOS app that displays trending gifs within a tableview and I have been going crazy trying to access the image url from the GIPHY API. I am currently using alamo fire to access the data and this is how my code looks so far.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchGiphyData()

    }
    
    func fetchGiphyData() {
    
        let request = AF.request("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=zONZGFIbbvYDBjLEBlgKxLjbsClfmptw&limit=25&rating=pg-13")
        
        request.responseDecodable(of: GiphyData.self) { (response) in
            guard let gifs = response.value else { return }
            print(gifs.height)
            
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how my data collection is set up for the JSON info.

```
import UIKit

struct Data: Codable {
    var data: [ImageInfo]
}

struct ImageInfo: Codable {
    var images: ImageTypes
}

struct ImageTypes: Codable {
    var original: GiphyData
}

struct GiphyData: Codable {
    var url: String
    var height: String
}

struct GiphyImages: Codable {
    var giphyImages: [GiphyData]
}
```

Here is the API info from GIPHY

```
{
"data":[
{
"type":"gif"
"id":"If1a3H7OHi8vmiCTpW"
"url":"https://giphy.com/gifs/nhl-draft-nhl-2019-prospects-If1a3H7OHi8vmiCTpW"
"slug":"nhl-draft-nhl-2019-prospects-If1a3H7OHi8vmiCTpW"
"bitly_gif_url":"https://gph.is/g/Zdx6J5o"
"bitly_url":"https://gph.is/g/Zdx6J5o"
"embed_url":"https://giphy.com/embed/If1a3H7OHi8vmiCTpW"
"username":"nhl"
"source":""
"title":"Ice Hockey Sport GIF by NHL"
"rating":"g"
"content_url":""
"source_tld":""
"source_post_url":""
"is_sticker":0
"import_datetime":"2019-07-03 17:13:37"
"trending_datetime":"2022-06-04 03:31:37"
"images":{
"original":{
"height":"500"
"width":"500"
"size":"3765578"
"url":"https://media3.giphy.com/media/If1a3H7OHi8vmiCTpW/giphy.gif?cid=84449cd9g1p95f9hyvvtbnajoj9j2ma4tnrpfcurbplr6brq&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g"
```

I am just trying to get the url under original so I can display the image within the table view. Does anyone know why I cant access the url?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't name your custom struct/classes `Data`, because there it already exists in Swift, so you might need to disembiguate each time (it's a pain)... You wrote `responseDecodable(of: GiphyData.self)`, but your response is a `Data`, not a `GiphyData`, you should have an error, no?

Comment: Try to rename Data Struct to something else like GiphyResponseData  and then instead of parsing response to GiphyData, replace that with GiphyResponseData. as below.

request.responseDecodable(of: GiphyResponseData.self)

Comment: @FaranRasheed I was trying to put the data into the struct GiphyImages to create the array of urls but Im not sure if that is correct

Comment: @FaranRasheed That actually worked! I updated the Data struct to GiphyReponseData and now parsing through that struct. Now I just need to upload all those urls into the tableview

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote my comment so others may benefit.